# Errors when trying to install 19.04 on HP Envy x360 (Ryzen 2500u)

Tags: system-installation, hp, 19.04

I've been trying to install ubuntu on my laptop, but keep running into the same error...

[drm:amdgpu_init [amdgpu]] *ERROR* VGACON disables amdgpu kernal modesetting

I've tried installing in both UEFI and non, and tried a handful of kernal command lines but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got to the bottom of this in the end...

I had to replace "quiet splash" with "noapic noacpi nosplash" in the GRUB params.
(Make sure "nomodeset" is also in there).

Once it was installed, I changed the GRUB params so that it always booted that way (can remove "nosplash" and replace with "quiet splash" again if you want.

Touchscreen and everything was working out of the box on the 5+ kernal.